# getHeadHtml() not outputting CSS included with {% includeCss %}

Tags: templating, getheadhtml

I think there is a bug in the getHeadHtml function of craft. In the Documentation (https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includecss) it says:

> Your CSS snippet will be output by the getHeadHtml() function. If you aren’t calling that function anywhere, Craft will insert it right before the HTML’s < /head> tag.

But in my templates it works only, if the tag getHeadHtml() is placed after the includeCss Tag.
So the following simple Example does not work as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Here should the CSS start --> 
        {{ getHeadHtml() }}
    <!-- Here should the CSS end --> 
  </head>
  <body>

      {% set myCss %}
        .content {
            color:  red;
        }
      {% endset %}


      {% includeCss myCss %}

  </body>
</html>
```

It outputs the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Here should the CSS start --> 

    <!-- Here should the CSS end --> 
  <style type="text/css">
  .content {
            color:  red;
        }
  </style></head>
  <body> 
  </body>
</html>
```

It outputs the CSS before the closing < /head> Tag and not between the two comments. Is there any workaround/fix for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an order of operations issue. The documentation is correct, but incomplete.

`getHeadHtml()` will only output head HTML that was queued up for it *before* the function was actually called. Any head HTML that is queued up *after* you've called `getHeadHtml()` will end up getting inserted in the default location - right before the `</head>` tag.

So, if you had this in your template instead:

```html
{% includecss %}
  .content {
      color:  red;
  }
{% endincludecss %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Here should the CSS start --> 
        {{ getHeadHtml() }}
    <!-- Here should the CSS end --> 
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then the CSS would get included between the HTML comments as you’d expect.